# Advanced MySQL Query Grouping

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following table

Table: item
field: id | timestamp | status

id is just auto inc key
timestamp is m:d:y h:m:s
status will just be 1 or 2

I was to generate a report such as the following:

```
Time Passed | Count of status = 1 | Count of status = 2
0-3hrs  |  2 |   9
3-6hrs  |  1 |   5
6-9hrs  |  8 |   14
0-12hrs  |  0 |   99
```

etc etc

So in summary, the report groups each status (1 or 2) in sums of 3 hours blocks

What I am doing can pretty easily be done using php to manipulate the data, but I am wondering if it can be done with just mysql query

Comment: So the timestamp is saved a string similar to: `6:7:2013 19:42:37`?

Comment: "timestamp is m:d:y h:m:s" Why? Pity the poor data type.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(
  FLOOR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) / 3)*3, '-',
  FLOOR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) / 3)*3+3, 'hrs'
 ) AS `Time Passed`,
 SUM(status=1) AS `Count of status = 1`,
 SUM(status=2) AS `Count of status = 2`
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY `Time Passed`;
```

Tested on MySQL 5.5.31.  Here's the output:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Time Passed | Count of status = 1 | Count of status = 2 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 0-3hrs      |                   2 |                   9 |
| 3-6hrs      |                   1 |                   5 |
| 6-9hrs      |                   8 |                  14 |
| 9-12hrs     |                   0 |                  99 |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

No guarantees about performance.  This is bound to do a table-scan.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint.

I would try to express time passed as time passed :).

So I would start with something like: `DATEDIFF(hour, timestamp, start_timestamp) / 3`.

Expression should return natural numbers starting from 0 for each next period of time.

Then you can `GROUP BY` expression above and `COUNT()` statuses.

I don't have MySQL under my hand to test that, but I am sure there are function which can help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can take your date and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, pass them through [DATEDIFF()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

```
DATEDIFF(hh, @date1, @date2)
```

will return the difference in hour

In a [SQL function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) that you will have declared before your SQL query.

With a simple while, you do that enough time to cover the day, group by the date_difference and use the [COUNT()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp) function to count the status.